# Unable to start a spring boot web application with spring batch admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to run a web application with embedded tomcat including a number of spring batch jobs and the spring batch admin. However when I try to run the generated fat jar I get the following error, can anybody from spring batch or boot team help:

```
Error registering Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/*,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
```

Adding more information:
Version of spring boot: 1.1.9.RELEASE from spring.io parent pom version 1.0.3.RELEASE
I tried running it from STS as well as using mvn spring-boot:run with the same effect.
The batch jobs read from a file and write to hornetq.

The complete stack trace is as follows:

```
2014-11-14 14:22:45.236 ERROR 404 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Error registering Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/*,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none`

javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: null
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411)`
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)`
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)    
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6506)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/*,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I would say too little information. Post the full stack trace and some of your configuration. Also are you running standalone or deploying to a server...

Comment: That's still not really enough information. Can you provide more details of your configuration and your application's dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the name is not a valid object name: `//localhost/*`

Could you try with a different name, or either escape or [quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html#quote-java.lang.String-) the name. This should fix the problem.